# Bootstrap moving logo

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, navbar

please I need advice. I am trying to move my logo in nav more to the right as I did with search form `.navbar-right` there is `margin-right 150px`, and I tried it also with `.navbar-right` included my logo and `margin-left` just don't work. When I have no `div` class `navbar-right` and trying to `margin-left`, it moves my nav to left also.

Would you be so kind and help me with this solution.

```css
/* nav */

.navbar-right {
  margin-right: 150px;
}

.navbar-left {
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.nav {
  margin-left: 500px;
  position: static;
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.navbar-logo {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 75px;
  margin-top: 14px;
}

.form-control {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
      <div class="navbar-left">
        <img class="navbar-logo" src="img/logo.png">
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search website">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `margin-left: 150px;` in `.navbar-left` to your desired amount.

Comment: I did and nothing happened

Comment: It does in your snippet

Answer (score 0):

just use    `.navbar-left {padding:12px;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can increase padding-left on your logo element. Or you can make it on your navbar-left div

Comment: Yes its easy but like I said it will move my <ul> to the right also. I just wanna position my logo

Comment: Can you post for me your jsfiddle. In your sniper code I set padding for .navbar-logo and it look fine.